# A question regarding sheaf cohomology

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

I am trying to understand a statement from http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1562, saying
"... $H^1(\Sigma^x,T\Sigma) = 0$ since $H^1(\Sigma^x,\mathcal{O}) = 0$ and the Mittag-Leffler problem is solvable on the non-compact Riemann surface $\Sigma^x = \Sigma\backslash\{X\}$." (p.16). Here  $\Sigma$ is a compact Riemann surface, $X\in\Sigma$ and $T\Sigma$ is the holomorphic tangent sheaf.

To my understanding, the second and third statement of the quote are equivalent, but how does the first one ($H^1(\Sigma^x,T\Sigma) = 0$) follow? Can the holomorphic tangent sheaf of a non-compact Riemann surface be identified with the sheaf of holomorphic functions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the tangent sheaf of a non-compact Riemann surface $X$ can be identified with the sheaf of holomorphic functions:

**Any  holomorphic locally free sheaf of any rank on a non-compact Riemann surface is holomorphically trivial !**

Amazing, eh?
You can find a proof on page  229 of [Forster's masterful book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Lectures_on_Reimann_Surfaces.html?id=iDYBTCVCO_IC&redir_esc=y).

**Edit**
At Jason's request let me translate the displayed statement into  an equivalent one not involving sheaves:

**Any  holomorphic vector bundle  of any rank on a non-compact Riemann surface is holomorphically trivial !**

Comment: Ok, but then line of argumentation in the quote is even less clear to me. Why doesn't he say "$H^1(\Sigma^x,T\Sigma)=0$ since the holomorphic tangent bundle on the non-compact Riemann surface $\Sigma^x$ is holomorphically trivial"? (Also, what is a locally free sheaf?)

Comment: Dear Jason, I have addressed your parenthetical question in an Edit. As to why the author didn't use that result, how would I know ? I would *conjecture* (but certainly not claim)  that he didn't know it. Indeed, even specialists in algebraic geometry are often surprised when I evoke that result, whereas the author seems to be a (mathematical) physicist.

Comment: Dear Georges: count me among the surprised. Amazing indeed!

Comment: Dear @Asal, great ! My list of very competent algebraic geometers who didn't know the result in question has just increased by one unit!

Comment: Dear @Georges, I am sorry but you have not answered my question in parenthesis, but rather cited the statement in Forster's book. Anyway, I am still confused: If a holomorphic vector bundle is holomorphically trivial, why does it imply that the corresponding (first) sheaf cohomology is trivial?

Comment: @Jason: if $H^1(\Sigma^x,\mathcal O) = 0$ then the $H^1$ of any trivial bundle l on $\Sigma^x$ like $T_{\Sigma} $ is zero too  . Any Mittag-Leffler distribution is solvable if $H^1(\Sigma^x,\mathcal O) = 0$ (Forster, Theorem  page 147).